# Javascript Main Function Fires First Before the Sub Function Inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I have a simple dialog box which has a Save and Cancel button on my MVC project. On the save button, I need to fire a function which will return a value and this value will be used for my if and else condition.

The problem is even though I put the function on my save button, it is not firing first. This is my code:

```
 $("#divMain").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "SAVE": function () {
                    var returnValue = fncApprove();
                    alert("Second");

                    //if and else condition here based on the returnValue variable 
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
            }
        });
```

On function **fncApprove** which I am calling inside the **Save** dialog box:

```
function fncApprove() {
        var objData = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("Approve", "Main")',
            data: objData,
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("First");

            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    }
```

The output of this is that alert box "**Second**" is first appearing instead of "**First**" alert box. Do I need to modify something here so that "**First**" will appear first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make fncApprove return callback and then execute your if and else

```
function fncApprove(callback) {
    var objData = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("Approve", "Main")',
        data: objData,
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
           alert("Error");
           callback(error);
        }
    });
}



 $("#divMain").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "SAVE": function () {
                fncApprove(function(returnVal) {
                      alert("CallBack");
                      //if and else condition
                });

            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is that solved your problem or not ... the call back ??

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but the second alert box is not firing anymore. Is there a way that alert box first and second will fire?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Does  alert("First") fired or not ?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr I Edit the code with callback in case of error, Check that and see which alert fired !

Comment: I followed your code and the code is not running which has an error of: "Uncaught ReferenceError: fncBulkApprove is not defined".

Comment: There is no method named (fncBulkApprove) .. it is name is (fncApprove)

Comment: I am sorry, its "Uncaught ReferenceError: fncApprove is not defined"

Comment: I think because of return keyword .. i Cahnged to returnVal .. and I tested it and it is working !! .. If after this not working .. sorry .. I don't know why ?